# How would you say 绵延不绝的小山 and 一望无际的田野 in English

Tags: translation, idioms

How would you say 绵延不绝的小山 and 一望无际的田野 in English?

Continuous mountains, and large and large fields?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You are pretty close. One thing to note is that `小山` is more accurately translated as "hill" and not "mountain."

Both of these contain what could be considered a 成语 (four-character idiom), and both idioms are very similar.

`绵延不绝的小山` essentially translates as "endless hills" and `一望无际的田野` basically means "fields as far as the eye can see."

For more literal translations of the individual idioms, `绵延不绝` means "continuing and stretching without cease," whereas `一望无际` means "one look without end."

Answer (score 2):

"Rolling hills stretching on endlessly" and "fields as far as the eye can see."  But is this really a question about Chinese?